# Regex php matches

Tags: php, regex

I want to check if words contains prefix with `preg_match` function : 
If I have `post_word` or `best_word

SO my prefixes are `post` and `best`.

Which pattern should I use here?

I tried:

```
((?:best_|post_)("word":)\s*("?[^,}"\s]+"?),?)
```

It should match these terms:

- best_word
- post_word
- word
- Word
- best_Word
- post_Word

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: `\b(?:post|best)\B`

Comment: so i can accept only word with : post_word and best_word  because "word" i used as a body of my regex :

Comment: @Saad, I gave you your answer ^ that will work for any word with a prefix of `post` or `best` if you need to ensure `_` follows it, then add it to the expression. This isn't a code-writing service. Show us what you've tried, explain what isn't working, etc. We can help you find the issues in your code and tell you what's incorrect/correct and go from there.

Comment: I have to make a regex wich acept only this list of word :               
   best_word, post_word, word, Word, best_Word, post_Word

Comment: That's an entirely different question. And what's the context for this

Comment: can I do like this : ((?:best_|post_)("word":)\s*("?[^,}"\s]+"?),?)

Comment: @Saad, Maybe, idk what the strings are, so maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a list of alternations in an capture group by using the `|`. You should use word boundaries so you don't get partial matches.

```
/\b(?<prefix>post_|best_)?word\b/i
```

The named capture group isn't needed here, just to show where the prefix is.

```
/\b(?:post_|best_)?word\b/i
```

will function the same.

It is unclear what you are doing with quotes, spaces, colons, and commas in your regex. From your example strings this regex should work:

https://regex101.com/r/6b8ijy/2/